# Trying to create Pacman

Tags: animation

I'm working on making 3d Pacman in unity, and I'm trying to create Pacman himself in blender. I've never used blender before, so this is proving to be seriously challenging. Can anyone help a girl out?

EDIT: I should also mention, I'm not just trying to model him, but make his mouth animation

Comment: Do you want him to be flat/2d, or like a ball?

Answer (score 3):

Pacman is pretty simple to model

1. Start by adding a sphere: <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>>*Mesh*>*Shphere*
2. Hit <kbd>F6</kbd>, in the properties window that is provided, change the segments to 24.
3. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode.
4. Rotate him by 90<sup>o</sup> on the X axis, <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X90</kbd>
5. Right Mouse click while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> on The face loops you'd like to delete for his mouth. You may need to select additional faces using the Right Mouse Button.

[image]

5. Use <kbd>X</kbd>>*Faces* to delete

There are a few more steps to add eyes:

1. Select a face on the one side you'd like his eye(s) to go over

   [image]
2. Snap the 3D cursor to it, using <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>>*3D cursor to selected*
3. Exit edit mode, <kbd>Tab</kbd>
4. Add another sphere.
5. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>>*Selected to cursor* to position your eye.
6. Scale it to the correct size using <kbd>S</kbd>
7. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to re-center the cursor
8. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>>*Origin to 3D curosr to move the origin of your eye to the center*
9. Add a mirror modifier using the modifier panel.

To animate the Pacman, instead of deleting the faces covering his mouth, split them down the middle <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, and then rotate them to alin with the upper lip. You can use this as a shape key. You will then need one with is mouth closed and you're good to go, simply animate between the shapekeys.

If the shape keys don't provide satisfactory results, You can try using somthing like the hook modifer, with an empty for each row of verts.

Comment: None of those key shortcuts work for me, I'm on a Mac

Comment: Also, I'm trying to make an animated version, with the mouth that opens and shuts

Comment: Use Option for Alt and Command For Ctrl

Comment: @SamanthaWolf It helps if you specify that in the question, but my advice to you is watch some tutorials first, the steps to make him animate are quite complex

Comment: Rough idea: Instead of deleting those faces, you'll want to split them down the middle, add a shape key, then scale them all the way up/down the the upper/lower lip of the packman.

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @iKlsR It *did*

Comment: OP is asking how to animate.

Comment: That was only an edit in the post after I wrote the answer

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Yes and we normally update answers to match the question. Doesn't have to be full steps, just an idea of what to do with a bit of detail.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I doubt that shape keys will do it, they save the position and then just shift the verts

Comment: you could just rip the one mouth edge, then shape keys all the way.